# Extract reflections from photo in Photoshop for use later?

Tags: post-processing, software, photoshop

I'm wondering if there's a Photoshop technique available to extract the 'reflective layer' (or an approximation of it) from photos of laptops/smartphones etc, so a screenshot of a website/app etc could be placed between the device and the reflective layer (meaning I'd be able to retain the extracted reflection details in a new layer)?

The motivation is to be able to generate more realistic looking product mockup shots without the need to manually draw in a new reflective layer.

Here's a sample photo that I'd like to be able to work with:

[image]

Comment: Paul, it looks like ElendilTheTall was able to help.  However, just so you know, the term 'Glare' has a specific meaning in photography. It's commonly referred to as lens flare. (cf ISO 9358:1994 Optics and optical instruments -- Veiling glare of image forming systems -- Definitions and methods of measurement).  So if there is a way you can edit your question and remove the reference to glare, this question and answer might be even more useful for future readers.

Comment: No worries, glare reference removed for future readers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simply select and copy the screen/glare you want to overlay, and paste it to a new layer. Set the Blending Mode to Hard Light. Then paste in your product image in a new layer and place it underneath the glare layer (you will obviously need to do some jiggery pokery to fit this image onto the screen in the photo).

Result:

[image]